# PHP curl lower SSL security (ca md too weak error)

Tags: php, ssl, curl, openssl, php-curl

I am trying to send simple GET request with curl using my certificate and private keys:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_SSLCERT => '/path_to/cert.pem',
    CURLOPT_SSLKEY => '/path_to/key.pem',
));

curl_exec($curl);
$error = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($error);
die();
```

the equivalent command in terminal would be:

`curl -GET --key key.pem --cert cert.pem https://example.com`

Running this curl i get this error - `could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:140AB18E:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate:ca md too weak, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)`

From my understanding, this is caused because the certificate that i am using is signed with md5 hash. ([How to fix SSL issue SSL_CTX_use_certificate : ca md too weak on Python Zeep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218876/how-to-fix-ssl-issue-ssl-ctx-use-certificate-ca-md-too-weak-on-python-zeep))

I cant re-create these keys, so the solution i found is to lower the ssl security level (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level), to do so i need to edit my `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` file, specifically this part - `CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1` (set from SECLEVEL=2, to SECLEVEL=1).

After editing my `openssl.cnf`, if i run my curl command in terminal - it works. However the problem still remains if i run it in PHP.

I tried setting up different curl options, but nothing seem to work.
Here are the curl options that i tried:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'TLSv1'
CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1'
```

Is there a way to fix this without editing openssl.cnf file by just setting some curl options?

Comment: Having the same issue with a site hosted with 1and1/IONOS. Have no control over certificate so need to change certificate level in cURL request. Seems to ignore changing CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST though

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you can pass custom openssl config to php cli and came up with one possible (ugly) solution to this problem:

1. Create a separate openssl.cnf file with lowered security settings somewhere in your project:

> ```
> openssl_conf = default_conf
> [ default_conf ]
> ssl_conf = ssl_sect
> [ssl_sect]
> system_default = system_default_sect
> [system_default_sect]
> MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
> CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
> ```

2. Create a separate php example.php file that will make a curl request:

> ```
> $curl = curl_init();
>
> curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
>     CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com',
>     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
>     CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
>     CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
>     CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
>     CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
>     CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
>     CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
>     CURLOPT_SSLCERT => 'cert.pem',
>     CURLOPT_SSLKEY => 'key.pem',
> ));
>
> $response = curl_exec($curl);
> $error = curl_error($curl);
> curl_close($curl);
> ```

3. Now call this file and pass the custom openssl config with php cli in your main code via `shell_exec`:

> $cmd = shell_exec("OPENSSL_CONF=openssl.cnf php example.php");

This way you dont need to lower your openssl version/security for your whole project, instead it will be lowered only on this one request. Curl file can be modified to be more dynamic (custom url, query params, keys etc).